# How to add selected item to table Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner in react and i want to write item from select option in table cells but i don't know how.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {getMeals} from './../../../../../services/mealService';


function MakeMenuForm() {

    const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const onInit = async () => {
            let response = await getMeals();
            setMeals(response)
            console.log(response);
        }
        onInit();
    }, [])

    
    const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState(meals);
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");

    function handleChange(event) {
        setSelected(event.target.value);
         let vals = event.target.value
         ? meals.filter(meal => meal.name === event.target.value)
         : meals;
        setTableData(vals);
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <label htmlFor="meal">Choose meal: </label>
            <select id="meal"  onChange={handleChange} >{meals.map(meal => <option value={meal.idMeal}>{meal.name}</option>)}</select> <br></br><br></br>

            <table border="1" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Meal</th>
                        <th>Contect</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Meal type</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {tableData.map(meal =>(
                    <tr>
                        <td>{meal.name}</td>
                        <td>{meal.content}</td>
                        <td>{meal.price}</td>
                        <td>{meal.mealType}</td>

                    </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </form>
    )
}

export default MakeMenuForm;
```

this is my bad try :D

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your handler, you're doing this comparison:

`meals.filter(meal => meal.name === event.target.value)`

The value you're passing in is the idMeal (`<option value={meal.idMeal}>`), so change it to this:

`meals.filter(meal => meal.idMeal=== event.target.value)`

Comparing name === idMeal will almost certainly return 0 results each time, which is why your table is empty.

Comment: Thanks, but i want when i click on one item from select box, add this item into table. Something like make menu images (noodles , pasta, 10, regular) (stake, meat, 20, regular)... adding one by one with only click to items